Proc-macro (<2) support with rust analyzer 0.3.220 or later
On December 16, 2024 VSCode's Rust analyzer extension updated to v0.3.2220, which dropped support for proc macro versions <2, which Solana depends on in versions <2 (e.g. solana 1.18.17, etc).
Rust analyzer will report an error similar to the following:
The version of the proc-macro server (2) in your Rust toolchain is too old


The best current workaround is to disable updates for Rust Analyzer and pin to versions v0.3.2212 or earlier. Go to extensions -> uninstall -> install specific version.
Alternatively, disable proc macro checking with
{
    "rust-analyzer.cargo.loadOutDirsFromCheck": false,
    "rust-analyzer.procMacro.enable": false
}

But this impacts a lot of the Anchor lib and is not recommended.
